# My site CSS is not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i have recently bought a template for a Betting site for CSGO, 
but now when i'm setting it up i get these weird errors, if you go to the site and 
go to console you can see exactly what i get. How can i fix these problems? 
site is : csgohulk.com
like this one : main18.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
what is wrong ? 
and Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined ?

i can give you more info if you want..,

I have not tried so much because i'm not so good at programming 
so i really need help

thanks //Wiz

Comment: Is your site available online?

Comment: yes, just search for csgohulk.com

Comment: Open the console. You can see a lot of files have failed to load. Fix them, you might fix all the problems.

Comment: but the thing is, how do i fix the problems., thats the thing i need help with :)

Comment: script and css files are not placed where they should be,you need to upload them to your server

Comment: @hsh , where should they be placed? i have uploaded them..

Comment: for example jquery-1.10.2.js should be inside js folder in the root directory of your website.

Comment: i have my jquery in the /var/www/ , is that right ?

Comment: you need to add a folder named js and put it there.so chat.js should be in chat folder and so on.

Comment: i have a folder called js in cd/var/www/html , and i have all my JS scripts there

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be your jquery isn't loading from  http://csgohulk.com/js/jquery-1.10.2.js

You are getting a 404 (not found) error.

You should first check that this file is even present on your server. If it isn't that is your problem. It could also be that the file is there but there are permission issues to access it.

Try replace `<script src="/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>` in your html with `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">`

See if that fixes it. (if it does then fix your file at /js/jquery-1.10.2.js on your server to be the same as the one [here](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js))

Then if there are other files that aren't loading then fix them too. Until there are no 404 errors displaying in the console of the browser.

Comment: there are many other js files that don't exist, see [the website](http://csgohulk.com/)

Comment: Yes, I saw now. He will have to go through each of them one by one and make sure each is available.